# Is Generic Function and Type Constraints Generic Function polymorphism in swift

Tags: swift, generics, overloading

There are two function below

```
func append<T>(_ value: T){
......
}
```

---

```
func append<T: A>(_ value: T){
......
}
```

when i call them like this they perform polymorphism，but I can't get any theory basis from Apple,

```
let a:A = A()
append(a) //call func append<T: A>
let b:B = B()
append(b) //call func append<T>
```

why `append(a)` call `append<T: A>` ? Is Generic Function and Type Constraints Generic Function polymorphism in swift?

Comment: First of all, there are no such thing as templates in Swift, these are called generic functions. And please rephrase your question, it is really unclear what you're asking. If you're asking why is the function called with the type constraint in one case and why the one without the type constraint called in the other, it is because the compiler always tries to call the most specific implementation of an overloaded function.

Comment: Thank you very much . I mean `<T>` is template and `<T: A>` is type constraint.  This perform polymorphism, but I don't know why?

Comment: As already stated, there are no such things as templates in Swift, this is no C++. Have a look into __generic functions__, that's what these are called in Swift.

Comment: I saw it, and edit my qusetion again. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect you are seeing is actually function overloading (which is also called ad-hoc polymorphism).

When a function has several overloaded versions (in your case, a generic function without and a generic function with type constraints), the compiler will always try to call the version of the function that is most specific to your input arguments.

Hence for an input argument that satisfies the type constraint, the compiler will call, the function with the type constraint, while for an input argument that doesn't satisfy the type constraint, the version without the constraint will be called.

You can see this behaviour even better, if you declare a new class, `C`, which inherits from `A` and you also declare an overloaded version of `append`, where the type constraint will be for class `C`. In this case, any of the 3 overloaded versions could be called for class `C`, but the most specific one will be called again, in which the constraint is for class `C` itself.

```
class A {}
class B {}
class C:A {}

func append<T>(_ value: T){
    print("Most generic version called")
}

func append<T: A>(_ value: T){
    print("Version with type constraint for class A called")
}

func append<T:C>(_ value:T){
    print("Version with type constraint for class C called")
}

let a:A = A()
append(a) //calls func append<T: A>
let b:B = B()
append(b) //calls func append<T>
append(C()) //calls func append<T:C>
```

The same effect can also be achieved with overloaded functions that are not generic.

```
func myFunc(_ val: A){
    print("Non generic function with input argument of type A called")
}

func myFunc(_ val: C){
    print("Non generic function with input argument of type C called")
}

myFunc(a) //myFunc(_ val: A) called
myFunc(c) //myFunc(_ val: C) called
```

If you comment out `myFunc(_ val: C)`, `myFunc(_ val: A)` will be called in both cases, since `c` is a valid input argument for both versions of `myFunc`.